# From Word to LaTeX, how?

Tags: msword

I was wondering if there is any software tool that acts as a common word editor and it outputs LaTeX code. Some time ago I heard there were some software tools that did that? does anybody knows any of these?

Comment: LyX, Bakoma TeX, Scientific Word do something like that.

Comment: There is a [list of editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764) you can look at; some provide this functionality.

Comment: I think Bakoma TeX, pandoc are the commercial and open source ones out there but if you feel adventurous you can do stuff like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140195/copying-italics-text-from-word-to-latex

Comment: Some editors as Gummi have a preview window, so while you write LaTeX code on the left,  you can see the result on the right in almost real time. Actually I prefer this to any WYSIWYG that hide the LaTeX code and hope the best, but anyway LyX is a very good free midpoint option to star.

Comment: BTW, related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122724/what-is-the-optimal-latex-wysiwyg-editor-platform-quality-price-for-windows-8

Comment: There are related plugins for LibreOffice/OpenOffice but I don't know about Word.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really not clear to me what exactly you are after here, and I suspect the question if clarified will be a dupe in any case